# Flow package not installed in conda env creation

Tags: flow-project

I have no issue creating an conda environment with the given
environment.yml file, but the flow package its self is not installed within the environment. I receive the following error when attempting to import flow within my env:

`ModuleNotFoundError: No module named 'flow'`

This is true on both macOS Mojave and Ubuntu 18.04.
The work around is to install dependencies using pip.
`pip install -e .`

Comment: Can you post the contents of .yml?

Answer (score 0):

this is correct. Flow is not currently pip installable and there is a step in the setup instructions pointing you to do it. Sorry for the difficulty!

Comment: Could you point me to that step ? I cannot find it in the instructions here https://flow.readthedocs.io/en/latest/flow_setup.html#local-installation-of-flow

Comment: When you run `python setup.py develop` flow is installed. Check the docs, we have updated them now to make it clearer I hope!